# Formatting API response React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have an api response (body) that comes back like this:

```
"<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur tempor enim nec velit egestas scelerisque. Etiam id leo sit amet magna ornare scelerisque. Sed pretium mollis nibh dignissim consectetur.</p>"
```

When i render {body} in React it renders it with the enclosing "" is there a method to clean this response and just render it as html?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `enclosing ""` !

Comment: this seems to work: const markup = {__html: body} <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={markup}></div>